# Is it possible to have function calls as parameter defaults in php?

Tags: php

In php, this can be done:

```
function foo( $var = "bar" ){
    echo $var;
}

foo();         // output : bar

foo("cheese"); // output : cheese
```

I've tried to use a function instead like so:

```
function foo( $var = get_defined_vars() ){}
```

Which returned a parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

the obvious answer is the pass the variable like so

```
function foo( $var ){
    // do stuff
}

foo( get_defined_vars() );
```

however, the function is overloadable and can handle many params.

I usually use the function like:

```
foo( $var1, $var2, $var3 ... etc );
```

However I NEED the defined vars from the scope above the `foo` function, which means EVERYTIME I use the `foo` function I have to pass `get_defined_vars()`.

I find it pretty annoying how everytime I want to use this function I have to call `get_defined_vars();` Like so:

```
foo( get_defined_vars(), $var1, $var2, $var3 ... etc );
```

So PLEASE can anybody think of a way to over come this?

I tried this, also to no avail:

```
function foo(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_unshift( get_defined_vars() );
    call_user_func_array( "bar", $args );
}

function bar(){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: For me it sounds like you are trying to do something nasty. I'm sure there's a better solution available...

Comment: If the function needs all the defined variables from the parent scope, the only way is to pass them in as an argument. There is no way to fetch variables from "the scope above this one" unless "the scope above this one" is the global scope. I have to say though, having a function that relies on variables defined in the parent scope (or indeed, any scope that isn't the current one) by name sounds like bad design to me. Consider constructing and passing a rigidly defined object instead?

Comment: The reason is for debugging variables with there variable names, probably shoulda mentioned that somewhere!

Comment: The kind of functionality provided by `func_get_args()`, `get_defined_vars()` etc where they are magically able to see data specific to the scope from which they were called in not implementable as a user defined function. Which is a good thing - if it were you would see some *horrible* code out there, even worse than you see at the moment. But if you are debugging stuff, you would expect to need to pass the subject matter - e.g. `print_r()` doesn't magically know what you want it to show, you have to pass a value to it.

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch Ever heard something about XDebug? Really: Look at it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Like for properties only static values and arrays are allowed. Even if, I would not recommend it, because it makes a function call unpredictable.

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.
>
> http://php.net/functions.arguments#example-152

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
function foo( $var1, $var2, $varForDefinedVars=null ){
  if (is_null($varForDefinedVars)){
     $varForDefinedVars = get_defined_vars();
  }
}
```

Comment: That will only retrieve the variables in the local function scope, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants to achieve.